# Como restar la suma total de dos columnas que se encuentran en los tablas diferentes en SQLITE

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, sum

Las dos columna tienen el mismo nombre `CANTIDAD` así que intente hacer esto:

```
SELECT STOCK.ARTICULO AS A,
      (SUM(coalesce(STOCK.CANTIDAD ,0))-SUM(coalesce(PEDIDOL.CANTIDAD ,0))) AS C 
      FROM STOCK 
      INNER JOIN PEDIDOL 
          ON PEDIDOL.ARTICULO=STOCK.ARTICULO  
      GROUP BY A
```

Una tabla se llama `STOCK` y la otra `PEDIDOL`. Necesito que al agrupar por articulo me sume el total de `STOCK.CANTIDAD` y lo reste por la suma del total `PEDIDOL.CANTIDAD`, algo así como `SUM(STOCK.CANTIDAD)-SUM(PEDIDOL.CANTIDAD)`

Comment: El agrupamiento debiera ser así: `GROUP BY STOCK.ARTICULO`, pruebalo y cualquer cosa nos dicees.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, hice lo que me dijiste y no funciona... no entiendo porque arroja resultados equivocados, ejemplo en las entradas tengo la cantidad de 32 panes y en las ventas tengo que se vendieron 10 el resultado deberia ser 22 en el stock y me esta dando 12, en realidad he hecho muchos cambios intentando resolver el problema yen cada cambio me da un numero diferente.. veo que no hace bien la suma

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que al hacer un `JOIN` con `PEDIDOL`, estás duplicando los datos de `STOCK`. Lo que deberías hacer es una subconsulta,  solo de `PEDIDOL` para obtener la cantidad total:

```
SELECT S.ARTICULO AS A,
       coalesce(STOCK.CANTIDAD ,0) - P.CANTIDAD AS C 
       FROM STOCK 
       INNER JOIN (SELEC ARTICULO,
                         SUM(coalesce(CANTIDAD ,0)) AS CANTIDAD
                         FROM PEDIDOL 
                         GROUP BY ARTICULO
           ) P
           ON P.ARTICULO = S.ARTICULO
```

Comment: Hice la prueba y me da los mismos resultados solo que no agrupados, tengo dos dias tratando de resolver esto y pense que era sencillo

Comment: Tal vez el resultado no es el que esperas, pero no puede ser el mismo  que tu consulta inicial. Revisa un caso, toma un articulo ¿Cuantas filas hay en stock? ¿cual es la cantidad en esta tabla? revisa luego pedidol para el mismo articulo ¿cuantas filas tiene? ¿cuanto suma la cantidad?

Comment: SI..he verificado todo lo eso... mira intente hacerlo uniendo otra tabla deque se llama articulos, me da los resultados deseados solo que me los duplica

Comment: "SELECT ARTICULO.NOMBRE AS A," +
                " S.CANTIDAD - P.CANTIDAD AS C " +
                " FROM ARTICULO " +
                " INNER JOIN (SELECT ARTICULO,SUM(coalesce(CANTIDAD ,0)) AS CANTIDAD" +
                " FROM PEDIDOL " +
                " GROUP BY ARTICULO" +
                " ) P" +
                "  ON P.ARTICULO = S.ARTICULO " +
                "INNER JOIN (SELECT ARTICULO,SUM(coalesce(CANTIDAD ,0)) AS CANTIDAD" +
                " FROM STOCK " +
                " GROUP BY ARTICULO" +
                " ) S" +
                " ON S.ARTICULO = P.ARTICULO  "

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion y quiero compartirla! mi codigo final es:

SELECT ARTICULO.NOMBRE," +
                " S.CANTIDAD - P.CANTIDAD AS C " +
                " FROM ARTICULO " +
                " INNER JOIN (SELECT ARTICULO,SUM(coalesce(CANTIDAD ,0)) AS CANTIDAD" +
" FROM PEDIDOL " +
" GROUP BY ARTICULO" +
" ) P" +
"  ON P.ARTICULO = S.ARTICULO " +
"INNER JOIN (SELECT ARTICULO,SUM(coalesce(CANTIDAD ,0)) AS CANTIDAD" +
" FROM STOCK " +
" GROUP BY ARTICULO" +
" ) S" +
" ON S.ARTICULO = ARTICULO.NOMBRE